# Question about the shape of the waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves

What is the molecular level reason behind the pattern (sine function) of the waves?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to expand your question to clarify what you're asking. Sine waves generally occur when the potential energy of your system is quadratic i.e. $V(x) \propto x^2$.

Comment: Sine waves arise also in periodic structures, although there is some modulation added in this case.

Comment: This question might need some clarification. Do you mean: "On a molecular level, why do materials oscillate?"

Answer (score 1):

If you're at the molecular level, it's not really QM.

Further, consider the calculus of Fourier sine expansions. You can deconstruct any periodic waveform into a collection (possibly infinite) of sine waves.   As John Rennie mentioned, sinusoidal behaviour is a direct consequence of quadratic functions, and for better or worse, the forces in our universe (at least gravity and electrical) follow a quadratic function of distance from the source.

Comment: the quadratic is the first term in the tailor expansion of any symmetric potential so it is not surprising to see it all over the place, as usually higher terms have smaller contributions.

Answer (score 1):

The reason simple harmonic oscillators, and hence their sinusoidal solutions, are so ubiquitous, is that any generic system will look like SHM close to a stable equilibrium. Roughly speaking, this is because smooth potentials look like polynomials (this is Taylor's theorem, in essence), and the quadratic term is the first interesting piece.

Concretely, with a 1-dimensional potential $V(x)$, with an equilibrium at $x=0$, we have $V(x)\approx V(0)+V'(0)x+\frac{1}{2} V''(0) x^2$ for small $x$, where we ignore higher powers of $x$ because they are much smaller. Since we are at equilibrium, $V'(0)=0$, and the constant term does not effect the dynamics, so the most relevant term is exactly simple harmonic motion $V(x)=\frac{m}{2} \omega^2 x^2$.